# Facebook SDK on Android seems to be persisting old user data

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to log a user into Facebook using the Android Facebook SDK.  We have a Facebook app set up, and it's working on one of our devices.  However, when I try to log in on my test device, it shows me a screen saying

**[Application name] is misconfigured for Facebook login.  Press Okay to go back to the application without connecting it to Facebook.**

This is confusing given that it works on another device, and I have set the application up to use both a debug key and a release key, but *even weirder* is the fact that at the bottom of the screen it says

**You are logging into [Application name] as [developer who left the project a month ago].**

[developer who left the project a month ago] left the project a month ago.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled this app many dozens of times in the intervening period.  How on earth is his login data being persisted across all these sessions?  How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

If a user is logged into the official Facebook application, these settings will be used by the Facebook SDK for login.  I hadn't realized [developer who left the project a month ago] was still logged into the Facebook app.